# Can commonjs modules work without combining them using browserify?

Tags: javascript, browser, module, browserify, commonjs

Javascript code written as commonjs modules can work properly with the web page (processed by browser) before combining them into a single javascript file using browserify? Or it is necessary to combine them using browserify first ?